# The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: Security

Tags: ios, react-native, tvos, television

I developed the app for Android TV and Apple TV in **React Native**. The app is running fine with Android TV. But when I try to run in Apple TV, I get below error:

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/com.xxxx.app
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx
org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx: -1
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: Security ("PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7f8995e02cd0; org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx (Demo Tv); sdk: 11.4>").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=3):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7f8995e02cd0; org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx (Demo Tv); sdk: 11.4>)
        [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7f8995e02cd0; org.reactjs.native.example.xxxx (Demo Tv); sdk: 11.4>)
```

What I tried:

- Clean Project
- Edit scheme from iPhone to TV (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme)
- Removed ios/build folder

To run the app I used `react-native run-ios --simulator "Apple TV 4K"` command from the terminal.

React Native version is **0.55.2**

Xcode version is **9.4**

Comment: Did you figure out the issue that caused this? I'm currently experiencing this issue with Flutter on Apple TV. I'm trying to add Apple TV support to the Flutter Engine. I'm assuming it has something to do with bitcode.